# How to speed up node iteration in Umbraco?

Tags: .net, umbraco

I've written a search for a website that iterates through all nodes under a certain folder and then filters out nodes based on certain criteria. The site itself is used to search apartments. Here is the function I have for building the collection:

```
private static List<Apartment> GetApartmentsCollection()
        {
            List<Apartment> apartmentsCollection = new List<Apartment>();

            Document apartmentsContainer = new Document(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apartmentsContainerNodeId"]));

            if (apartmentsContainer.HasChildren)
            {
                Document[] buildings = apartmentsContainer.Children;
                foreach (Document building in buildings)
                {
                    if (building.Published)
                    {
                        // Store building id for apartment
                        int buildingId = building.Id;
                        if (building.HasChildren)
                        {
                            Document[] apartments = building.Children;
                            foreach (Document apartment in apartments)
                            {
                                if (apartment.Published)
                                {
                                    apartmentsCollection.Add(new Apartment(apartment.Id,
                                                                           buildingId,
                                                                           Convert.ToInt32(apartment.Text),
                                                                           (int)apartment.getProperty("apartmentType").Value,
                                                                           (int)apartment.getProperty("floor").Value,
                                                                           (int)apartment.getProperty("status").Value,
                                                                           (int)apartment.getProperty("bedrooms").Value,
                                                                           Convert.ToInt32(apartment.getProperty("price").Value),
                                                                           string.IsNullOrEmpty(apartment.getProperty("room1").Value.ToString()) == true ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(apartment.getProperty("room1").Value.ToString()),
                                                                           apartment.getProperty("room1Dimensions").Value.ToString(),
                                                                           string.IsNullOrEmpty(apartment.getProperty("room2").Value.ToString()) == true ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(apartment.getProperty("room2").Value.ToString()),
                                                                           apartment.getProperty("room2Dimensions").Value.ToString(),
                                                                           string.IsNullOrEmpty(apartment.getProperty("room3").Value.ToString()) == true ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(apartment.getProperty("room3").Value.ToString()),
                                                                           apartment.getProperty("room3Dimensions").Value.ToString(),
                                                                           string.IsNullOrEmpty(apartment.getProperty("room4").Value.ToString()) == true ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(apartment.getProperty("room4").Value.ToString()),
                                                                           apartment.getProperty("room4Dimensions").Value.ToString(),
                                                                           string.IsNullOrEmpty(apartment.getProperty("room5").Value.ToString()) == true ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(apartment.getProperty("room5").Value.ToString()),
                                                                           apartment.getProperty("room5Dimensions").Value.ToString(),
                                                                           string.IsNullOrEmpty(apartment.getProperty("room6").Value.ToString()) == true ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(apartment.getProperty("room6").Value.ToString()),
                                                                           apartment.getProperty("room6Dimensions").Value.ToString(),
                                                                           string.IsNullOrEmpty(apartment.getProperty("room7").Value.ToString()) == true ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(apartment.getProperty("room7").Value.ToString()),
                                                                           apartment.getProperty("room7Dimensions").Value.ToString(),
                                                                           apartment.getProperty("totalArea").Value.ToString(),
                                                                           apartment.getProperty("projectArea").Value.ToString()));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return apartmentsCollection;
        }
```

The only problem is that this takes a good 8-10 seconds or so (even though there are only ~150 nodes tops) which is too long.

Bear in mind this is just for retrieving the raw collection. I then filter out out results using a handful of linq statements which takes a further few seconds. Ultimately this leads to a search of ~150 nodes taking around 15 seconds which is far too long.

How can I speed this up?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use NodeFactory's Node to access your data instead of Document. Document accesses the database, which is where your performance issue comes from. NodeFactory accesses the Umbraco cache and is much faster. See [Difference between Node and Document](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/difference-between-node-and-document) for more details.

Another thing to note is that the cache only contains published nodes. So you won't have to do any checking to see if they are published.

Comment: Ah that's so amazing I could kiss you! I've been banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out - thanks!